# Cross Sectional vs. Time-Series Risk Premia Estimate

Tags: regression, asset-pricing

Consider the single factor model in time series form, e.g:

$$
r_t^i  = \alpha_i + \beta_i f_t +\epsilon^i_t \tag{1}
$$
Here $i$ is  not an exponent but a superscript, e.g. it represents the return on security $i$.

Assuming we have a single factor model, which then states that:
$$
\mathbb{E}[r^i] =\alpha_i  +  \lambda\beta_i \tag{2}
$$
e.g. the  average return for security $i$  is given by a  constant times its exposure to the common factor $f$ (whatever it may be). As such, there seem to be two ways of estimating $\lambda$. The first is the rather  simple/possibly too simple way - take equation $(1)$  and take empirical time-series averages so that:
$$
\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T r^i_t = \alpha_i + \beta_i \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T f_t + \underbrace{\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \epsilon^i_{t}}_{\text{Assumed to be zero}}
$$
so that the estimate of the risk premium is:$$
\hat{\lambda} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T f_t 
$$
For example, in the case of CAPM - this would just be the average return of the benchmark/index.

The other method is the  two stage, so-called **Fama-Macbeth** regression, which would estimate the $\beta_i$ for each stock through $N$ different time-series OLS regressions, and then for each estimated coefficient, run $T$ cross-sectional regressions to estimate $\lambda_t$ at each time $t$. It would the consider:
$$
\hat{\lambda} = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T\lambda_t
$$

**My Question**:  What exactly is the difference between the results  obtained in each of these procedures? I understand methodologically they are quite different, but I am wondering how their estimates of risk premia would differ in practice and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one is better at explaining asset pricing than [John Cochrane](https://www.johnhcochrane.com/). He explains it in detail in [his brilliant textbook](https://www.johnhcochrane.com/research-all/asset-pricing). The following videos from his video course are pure gold

- [2.2 Time-Series and GRS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbaCt0LA-x8)
- [2.3 Cross-Sectional Regressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxTfVIWZg34&t=89s)
- [2.4 Comments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKpDNspw-sM)
- [2.5 Fama-MacBeth Regressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkFon5Jhw-A)

The notes for Week 5b Notes on empirical methods of his course [Business 35150 Advanced Investments](https://www.johnhcochrane.com/business-35150-advanced-investments#lecture_notes) are also fantastic.

---

A few notes though

- Time series approaches only apply to traded assets. You can't use time series regression to find the price of consumption risk (because consumption growth isn't a traded return).
- Fama-MacBeth is a variant of the cross-sectional approach (think of constant betas)
- Using the time series approach, you run a regression to perfectly price the the risk-free asset and the factor. The risk premium is the mean of factor. The TS intercept is the cross-sectional error (= alpha).
- Using the cross-sectional (or FM) approach, you try to minimise pricing errors across all assets (and accept that risk-free rate and factor aren't perfectly priced).
- Importantly, if your asset pricing model is well-specified, both approahes (TS and CS) give you broadly similar results.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kevin - your explanation is quite clear. I have been reading through Prof. Cochrane's text although I have only made it through the portions on the theory of the SDF so far. Off topic but I also got to listen to him speak while a student at UofC and thoroughly enjoyed it

Comment: @rubikscube09 That's pretty cool. I also attended one of his talks and it was absolutely brilliant. Note that there are many videos, interviews and postcasts available with him online. It's always a great pleasure to listen to him