# Difference between Trader Behavior and Analysis/Inference

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, asset-pricing, momentum

In the academic literature - often "momentum" and "positive feedback" traders are used interchangeably. Like "Most researchers have found that institutional investors are momentum traders (also referred to as positive feedback traders and trend followers)"

Is the crucial difference - that momentum is computed as an aggregate while positive feedback is computed when individual trader data is available - so that herding can also be computed along with positive feedback?

How does one actually infer positive feedback from fama-french-carhart factors as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is no conceptual difference between momentum trading and positive feedback trading. There are funds trading momentum strategies that incorporate herding metrics on an individual security level.

In terms of the Fama-French-Carhart factors, the factor that is most relevant for inferring positive feedback is the momentum factor (UMD): The difference in returns between high momentum (winners) and low momentum (losers) stocks.

Comment: When we read Delong (1990) which uses "positive feedback" trader as a term - they do not refer it to momentum trading at all.  Jegadeesh and Titman (1993) use the term momentum for the first time.  In the conclusion they refer to De Long - "This interpretation is consistent with the analysis of
DeLong, Shleifer, Summers, and Waldman (1990) who explore the implications of what they call "positive feedback traders" on market price." However their momentum is relative (winners and losers are in deciles) and De Long's positive feedback is absolute. Does this clarify the issue?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, without the explicit sources you were working from it was difficult for me to understand. Going through DeLong (1990) Positive Feedback Investment Strategies and Destabilizing Rational Speculation and the subsequent literature, it seems to me 1.) that positive feedback strategies refers to time series momentum as opposed to cross-sectional momentum, as you noted, and 2.) that positive feedback is usually used as an explanation for momentum. With regards to your data/herding point, could you refer to additional material? The connection is still unclear to me.

Comment: Is your question possibly how time series momentum and cross-sectional momentum are connected? In that case Kevin's answer to this question might be of interest: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/71792/cross-sectional-vs-time-series-risk-premia-estimate

Comment: I understand the concept of time series and cross-sectional momentum - but when research papers use them interchangeably - i feel uncomfortable. However lets say that we have a fama-french-carhart regression output - we can conclude whether the portfolio manager is cross-sectional momentum driven or cross-sectional contrarian. However Herding, on the other hand, refers to the tendency of investors to follow the actions of other investors, rather than making independent investment decisions based on their own analysis or beliefs.

Comment: While both time series momentum and herding can lead to price movements in financial markets, they have different underlying causes and implications. How does one test for them at the same time?